# Can I remap y key in vim-surround plugin?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-surround

I use `langmap` to be able to use QWERTY-like layout for normal mode, and Bépo to input text.

**Key**      |      **Usage**
 `y`   maps to    `x`
 `ç`   maps to    `y`

However, I can’t use vim-surround to add surroundings with this config :

- `ç` does nothing
- `y` deletes the character under cursor (as expected).

**Question**
How can I configure vim-surround so that I can use `ç` instead of `y` to add surroundings ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you sure ç does nothing? The surround mappings are ds, cs, ys... so you may need ç followed by your langmapped s

Answer (score 1):

langmap has a bug -- [multiletter mappings do not work](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3018)

You can use keymap instead (and internal keymap switcher).

Well, if you want to have your own mappings anyway, check vim-surround:

https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/f51a26d3710629d031806305b6c8727189cd1935/plugin/surround.vim#L603

For your example it might be smth like:

```
nmap çs  <Plug>Ysurround
```